# Add two collections in clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

How to add two collections efficiently in clojure ? 
I tried following one. I want to know is there any other method efficient than this.

(reduce #(conj %1 %2) collection01 collection02)

Comment: not an answer to your question, but the reduce function could just be `conj`; reduce calls it with two arguments, so `#(conj %1 %2)` and `conj` are functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 12):

It depends on what you want to achieve. If what you want in the result is a collection of specified type, that contains all element of given collections, then [`into`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/into) is appropriate: `(into coll1 coll2)` returns collection of type `(type coll1)` with elements from `coll1` and `coll2`.

On the other hand, if you just want to iterate over many collections (i.e. create a *sequence* of elements in the collections) then it is more efficient to use [`concat`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/concat):

```
user> (concat [1 2 3] (list 4 5 6)) 
(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Answer (score 8):

use `into`:

```
user> (into [1 2 3] [4 5 6])
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
user> (doc into)
-------------------------
clojure.core/into
([to from])
  Returns a new coll consisting of to-coll with all of the items of
  from-coll conjoined.
nil
```